# Looping through variables to make many boxplots

Tags: r, loops

I am using from the package OlinkAnalyze and I am trying to make box plots.

```
    install.packages("OlinkAnalyze")
        library(OlinkAnalyze)
df = npx_data1
```

the code for the boxplot is:

```
plot <- df %>%
  na.omit() %>% # removing missing values which exists for Site
  olink_boxplot(variable = "Site", 
                olinkid_list = c("OID01216", "OID01217"),
                number_of_proteins_per_plot  = 2)
plot[[1]]
```

It takes values from the `olinkID` column. What I would like, is to loop through the column, choosing the next two `olinkID` at a time, to make boxplots, renaming the plot each time (e.g.plot 1 with `OID01216` and `OID01217` and plot 2 with `OID01218` `OID01219`

Comment: I'm not familiar with `olink_boxplot`, not sure if it must be specific to that function. I don't see `Oxwatchtime` in your data, is that something generated by the plot function?

Comment: Sorry, my mistake, edditing! Oxwatchtime is wrong variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used a while loop.

```
install.packages("OlinkAnalyze")
library(OlinkAnalyze)
df = npx_data1
i <- 1

ids <- as.data.frame(unique(df$OlinkID))

while(i <= nrow(ids)){
  print(i)
  x <- i+1
  temp <- ids[i:x,]
  plotx <- df %>%
    na.omit() %>%  #
    olink_boxplot(variable = "Site", 
                  olinkid_list = c(paste(c(ids[i,],ids[x,]))),
                  number_of_proteins_per_plot  = 2)

  plottemp <- assign(paste0("plot_",ids[i,],"_",ids[i,]),plotx)
  i <- i+2
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want the loop, you could write like this:

```
for i in seq(from = 1, to = length(data$OlinkID), by = 2){
    the plot code
  }
```

This way you can access the two observations you want by `data$OlinkID[i]` or `data$OlinkID[i+1]`.

So the boxplot code should be

```
plot <- data %>%
na.omit() %>%
olink_boxplot(variable = "Oxwatchtime", 
            olinkid_list = c(data$OlinkID[i],data$OlinkID[i+1]),
            number_of_proteins_per_plot  = 2)
```

If you want to save the plots, add a `ggsave()` or a `png()/pdf()` in the loop to save them externally or create a list with them using `ggarrange()` function from `ggpubr` package. Let me know if it works as you intended.

Answer (score 1):

`OlinkAnalyze::olink_boxplot()` plots several plots until all proteins specified under the `olinkid_list` argument are plotted. The `number_of_proteins_per_plot` argument determines the number of IDs plotted on one plot.

Try this:

```
library(OlinkAnalyze)
data("npx_data1")

ids <- unique(npx_data1$OlinkID)
olink_boxplot(npx_data1,
              variable = "Site", 
              olinkid_list = ids, 
              verbose = TRUE,
              number_of_proteins_per_plot  = 2)
```

The code runs for a while as each plot takes time to be generated. When it completes you can use the arrow buttons in RStudio to look at all the plots.